# Expressions/phrasal verbs for "when someone makes you a meal"

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs

When a person makes himself a meal, he says "treating myself with" but what can we say for when someone else makes you food?

Comment: I don't really understand the first part of your question. Firstly, the saying is usually "treat someone **to** something", not treat them *with* something.  Secondly, you wouldn't say you were treating yourself to something if you were just making yourself a meal.  Treating yourself to something means to allow yourself something special.  For example, you might say, "I wouldn't usually buy macadamia nuts, because they're so expensive, but I decided to treat myself today."

Comment: @stangdon: agreed- "treat yourself with" is usually followed by "respect", whereas "treat yourself to" is followed by some special indulgence. I agree that "**just** making yourself a meal" certainly would exclude the possibility of a treat, but that's not what the OP said. "Making a yourself a meal" without the "just" could involve a treat: it could be a special meal.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase that pops in my mind is *cooked for me*:

> I went over to Tim's house and he **cooked for me**.

Some might argue that this won't work if the meal doesn't involve heat from a stove or an oven, as in the case of sandwiches or a garden salad. If so, you can just use the verb *make*:

> We went over to Bob's house, and Melissa **made us lunch**.
>   We know we're in for a treat whenever Ed **makes us sandwiches**.

Another verb that can be used is *fed*:

> They hosted a wonderful picnic and **fed us** hummus.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question: when we are talking about some special delicacy, I can treat myself, you can treat yourself, he can treat himself, but it sounds wrong to say that you are treating me.

The problem is that [treat](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/treat) has multiple meanings. The verbal form "treat", meaning giving somebody a delicacy is only valid in a reflexive sense, for example "treat myself" or "treat yourself".

The expression "treat somebody **to** dinner" is similar, but this really means paying for a meal for somebody, rather than offering them a particular delicacy.

If you use "treat" without the  "to", the meaning is completely different, for example

> You have treated me badly.

It *is* possible to use "treat" in the situation you describe, but you would have to use the noun version:

> This is a real treat for me!

or

> [whatever it is] is a real treat for me!

If you want to put the emphasis on the person who is providing the treat, you could say

> You are spoiling me!

Comment: So if i say, my parents spoil me by making delicious chkicken roast, would that be okay?

Comment: Perfect! Bear in mind when using "spoil" in other situations that some people disapprove of spoiling children (giving  them everything they want), so it can have a negative meaning. You can call a child that is demanding and ungrateful a  "spoiled brat"